# UTM coordinate conversion to Geographic coordinates

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, utm, php

I have about 500 separate files containing GPS points in UTM coordinates from multiple zones.

I am looking for a simple and fast python or PHP script that i can use to carry out a batch conversion for these files.

Comment: What file format do you have?

Comment: The files are in Csv (spreadsheet) format

Comment: The procedure to identify the UTM *zone* is discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31178.

Answer (score 3):

[proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs) or [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/osr_tutorial.html) might be useful. We can probably provide better answers if you tell us what file format you want to convert from, the UTM zone, and the target coordinate system.

Comment: The files are in csv format but the problem here is that the UTM zones are not usually specified by the field men, because their job is based on locations using the Canadian dominion land survey (DLS) system. I am thinking of the possibility of identifying the UTM zone using the range and meridian information that i have on the DLS names. Please I will appreciate contributions on this

Comment: What is the target coordinate system?

Comment: The target coordinate system is NAD_1983_10TM

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to copy/paste your lat/long in UTM format to http://www.hamstermap.com - you will get them instantly converted to any other popular coordinate format.

Comment: Petra, do you happen to know what datum hamstermap uses? Considering it says "Decimal degrees (Google Maps)", I'm assuming that it's WGS84, but I just wanted to make sure before I trust the output. Thanks.